# The Tensorflow model can't completely delet and still occupy the CPU memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm working with optimize the the neural network architecture and hyperameters. For this reason, I build a for loop to sent in the hyperameters and build/train/evaluate a new model through each iteration. The example like that:

```
for k in range(10):
    #full_model() function is used to build the new model with 
    #hyperparameters l1,l2,l3
    md=full_model(l1,l2,l3)
    md.compile(optimizer='SGD',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    md.fit(trads,validation_data=vds,epochs=3)
    teloss,teacc=md.evaluate(teds)
```

and I try to completely remove the created model and free the occupied CPU memory after evaluation in the loop by add following code in the loop:

```
del md
gc.collect()
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
```

But I observe that the CPU memory will not free after add above code inside the loop and the usage of memory keep increasing while iteration. Finally, the process will be killed by system due to leak memory.

By the way, I have used some custom layers which save the sublayers and tensors inside the list. this kind of custom layers also be contained in a list during build whole model. I'm not sure wheter it is one of reason to cause this problem.The example persudo code like that:

```
class custom_layer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

   def __init__(self):
      self.layer_li=[layers.conv(),layers.Maxpool2d()....]
      ...

   def call(self,inputs):
    self.out1,self.out2=self.layer_li[0](inputs),self.layer_li[1(inputs)
    return [self.out1,self.out2]


class build_model(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        sub_layers_list=[sublayer_1(),sublayer2...]

   def call(self,inputs):
        self.x=self.sub_layers_list[0](inputs)
        for k in range(1,len(sub_layers_list)):
           self.out=sub_layers_list[k](self.out)

        return self.out
```

Can anyone help me to work this way without leak of memory?
Thank in advance for any help!

**edited**
my code run in tensorflow2.1 with ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I am also investigating a possible tf-related memory leak, so I am interested in your problem. Could you provide a runnable minimal example, possibly in a google colab?

Comment: Hi,  @ Zaccharie Ramzi. I found this problems seems not appear in colab, I'm working experiment for further verification of this guess. If have any progress I will share on here.

Comment: I have the same problem, my memory leak is not reproducible in colab.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, this problem is resolved by change the OS to Windows. If anyone have wiser way to deal it in Ubuntu, welcome to give some suggestion or comment.